# Bootstrap Create a large button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i create a large button in bootstrap with responsive

just like the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEBwc.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `class="row"` to `wrap` div and `col-xs-4` (or `col-md-4`...) to div that wrap the button...**

Use `btn-lg` and also own css to override bootstrap definition...

I use `width:100%;` because you want big buttons(as you said...)

```css
    .btn-default{
      width:100%;
      background-color:orange!important;
      margin:5px!important;
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Basic</button>
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Basic</button>
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Basic</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Basic</button>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Basic</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i expected

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Here I have provided an example with three large buttons:

**HTML:**

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large</button>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn
{
  width:250px;
}
```

Hopefully this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

use .btn-lg and .btn-block class of bootstrap

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Block level button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Block level button</button>


<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want big button ,you can use the 'btn-l' class.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
```

If you want to change the button's width when the screen changed, you can use [flexbox utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/), here I used 'd-flex' and 'flex-grow-1'.

```css
.bd-highlight{
  background:red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
  <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">Third flex item</div>
</div>
```